# Smooth autoregressive model

Tags: matrices, upper-lower-bounds, vector-auto-regression

I am trying to build an autoregressive model such that $\mathbf{W}^t = \mathbf{W}^{t-1}\mathbf{M}$ where $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R^{k \times k}}$ and $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R^{p \times k}}$ where $p > k$. Is there a constraint to put on matrix $\mathbf{M}$ such that $\mathbf{W}$ smoothly evolves?

Edit 1: Here smoothly means that difference between each element of $\mathbf{W}^{t-1}$ and $\mathbf{W}^{t}$ is not very large or we can say that the difference is bounded by some term $\alpha$.

Comment: Have you tried setting $M=I+\alpha K$ for $\alpha$ small and $K$ with elements of $O(1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following constraint: *All eigenvalues of $M$ must have absolute values less than $ 1$.*

Observe that $W^t=WM^{t-1}$.

Define a [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) $\|\|$ as follows: Let $\|M\|=\max_{i,j}|[M]_{i,j}|$ be the absolute value of the element of $WM$ whose absolute value is greatest.

On this Wikipedia page about [Spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Power_sequence), it is proved that , for any matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$, $\|M^t\|$ tends to zero if and only if all eigenvalues of $M$ have absolute value less than $1$. The same page also proves that $\|M^t\|$ tends to infinity when $M$ has an eigenvalue with absolute value greater than $1$.

If $M^t$ is bounded then $W^t$ is bounded and, since $W^t-W^{t-1}=W^{t-1}(M-I)$, the difference $W_{t+1}-W_{t}$ is also bounded.

Comment: I Believe you mean , "All eigenvalues of M must have values _close to_ 1"

Comment: @user619894 Why should the eigenvalues be close to $1$? And could you explain your comment about setting $M=I+\alpha K$?

Comment: As you said, the bound is $W^{t-1}(M-I)=\alpha W^{t-1}K$ so having $|\alpha|<<1$ is a good control on the distance. Since $M$ is near identity, its eigenvalues are near 1.

Comment: @user619894 I get why $W^{t-1}(M-I)=\alpha W^{t-1}K$, but that doesn't tell me anything about the limiting behavior of $W^t$ in terms of $M$.

Comment: I guess the real issue is what is meant by "near". I interpreted as meaning near in a proportional manner, that is, a small factor of $W^t$

Comment: @AngelaPretorius Can you also take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714463/simulate-autoregressive-model?