# Simulate autoregressive model

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, vector-auto-regression

I am trying to simulate an autoregressive model such that $\mathbf{W}^t = \mathbf{W}^{t-1}\mathbf{M}$ where $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ and $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times k}$ where $p > k$. Also, squared $\ell2$ norm of each row of $\mathbf{W}$ matrix is $1$ Would it possible to sample $\mathbf{M}$ such that $\ell2$ norm of each row of $\mathbf{W}$ matrix is $1$?

Edit 1: I am thinking of using optimization to solve it by writing $p$ constrained equations where equation corresponds to the constraint that squared $\ell2$ norm of each row of $\mathbf{W}$ matrix is $1$. This will be overdetermined system of equations. Is there a simpler solution to it?

Comment: Please [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: @Saad It is a part of a research problem, so cant provide more details.